# DB to use for coding a twitter clone for a beginner

Tags: django, twitter, redis

I am coding (learning to) a twitter clone and i am a beginner, just built a few apps using Django. Should I be learning Redis and use it or go with MySQL, Postgres etc in the beginning and then use Redis for better performance?

Comment: Redis is not a relational database. You can use it to create a twitter clone, but you will not be able to use the Django ORM. So if you are trying to learn Django then stick with a supported database like PostgreSQL or even sqlite3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to just learn, you should go with SQLite3 if you wanna drop and recreate the database several times.
If you want something a little bit more robust for learning, go with MySQL. Easy to install localy, you have a lot of frameworks to connect and make queries and validate data.

Don't use Redis as the database here, since you'll have a hard time using the Django ORM.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks. :)  This did help! I have started my project using SQLite itself.